# Modal form that validates and returns meesage to user in pop up

Tags: forms, modal-dialog

I'm new to this and have been looking online for an example and can not find one. I have a modal pop up form that I would like to be able to validate, email and return a success or error message within the pop up. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction. I have a modal button that when clicked opens the form.

Modal Button

```
<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#sendModal' class='btn btn-default' title='Send to a friend'><i class='fa fa-send'></i> <span>Send to a friend</span></a>
```

Form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="sendModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4>Send to a friend</h4>
            <div class="alert alert-error fade in"> This option is correctly not working.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Friend's Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is too broad. can't give you fully working example but can point you in the right direction.

First you need `validation plugin` to validate the form inputs, as you are using bootstrap framework, best choice will be [BootstrapValidator plugin](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) you can find many working example [here](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/examples/) **OR** [BootstrapFormValidation Plugin](http://formvalidation.io/) and you can find working examples [here](http://formvalidation.io/examples/) but I'm going with `BootstrapValidator plugin`

[Fiddle example with BootstrapValidator](http://jsfiddle.net/rz9gzc0q/)

After validation, you are asking to send an email (but no page refresh as you want to show the success or error message in modal)

For this step you need Ajax to pass the validated input values and get the response back.

If you check this [examples](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/examples/) page, you will find an example `Using Ajax to Submit Form` and to get the response back (success or error) you can use [submitHandler option](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/settings/#submit-handler).

HTML

```
<a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#sendModal' class='btn btn-default' title='Send to a friend'><i class='fa fa-send'></i> <span>Send to a friend</span></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="sendModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4>Send to a friend</h4>
             <div id="message"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="signup" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#" data-bv-submitbuttons="button[type='submit']">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>

                            <label class="control-label"></label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BootstrapValidator Script

```
$('#signup').bootstrapValidator({
  message: 'This value is not valid',
  submitButton: '#signup button[type="submit"]',
  submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'file.php', //Here you handle the Post request via Ajax
          data: $(form).serialize(),
          success: function(result) {
              $("#message").html(result); //This will show the message in modal
              $("#signup").data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm(); //This will reset the form inputs after success call.
          }
      });
      return false;
  },
  feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The username is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

in last create `file.php`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
   //Get Post Values from Ajax Request
   //Send Email Use PHP mailer https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer
   //Check success or errors with if / else condition e.g
   if($mail->send()) {
      echo"<div class="alert alert-success fade in"> Everything is good and working.</div>";
   } else {
      echo"<div class="alert alert-error fade in"> There is something seriously wrong or may be something not working as plan.</div>";
   }
}
?>
```

Note-1: Above code example is not fully tested.

Note-2: working with jQuery and Ajax, always check browser console log for errors for heads-up.